# Who can give me about this grammar in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
    ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
window[ud]= function(o){
    success && success(new Date(o.datetime), o);
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
    return s;
})());}
```

What is the use of `window[ud]` and what does `success && success()` mean?
Another question is why we need an extra pair of brackets in the last line when calling appendChild outside its anonymous function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`success && success(...)` basically means "if `success` exists, call `success()`." It's equivalent to the following:

```
if(success) {
    success(new Date(o.datetime), o);
}
```

`window[ud]` means "the property of `window` named `ud`." So if `ud` were (for example) `"json12341234"` then it would be equivalent to `window.json12341234`.

The extra pair of parentheses calls the anonymous function. So instead of passing that function, you're passing the result.

Answer (score 0):

`window[ud]` is a callback that's going to called automatically by the JSON-P Javascript that's going to come in from the XMLHttpRequest.

`success&&success()` is a shortcut for `if (success) { success(); }`.

The extra pair of brackets mean that the anonymous function will be called directly, in effect meaning that appendChild will actually be called with the anonymous function's *returned* value instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. `success && success(...)` means that `success` might be a function and if it passed to the function it will be called with `new Date(o.datetime), o`
2. extra pair of brackets is for immediate function call, which is inside the brackets
3. `window[ud]` might be replaced with `window.ud` - global variable definition